# wordpress exclude posts from loop if only has one specific category

Tags: wordpress

I have this category which is "community-posts" I don't want it to appear on my homepage loop so I added this to my query

```
<?php query_posts(array('showposts' => 4,'category__not_in' => $id_communityposts,));?>
```

This is working fine with me but some "community-posts" I want them to be featured on the homepage loop. (exception)

so I want to only exclude the posts that has one category as "community-posts" if it has this category and more its shows normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing [do not use query_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/62744) - it should never be used as it alter the main query. Use `get_posts` instead - it's much safer and perform the same task.

To answer your question, let's first imagine how the query would look in SQL (assuming your `$id_communityposts` is equal to 2) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE 
    wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND
    (
        (wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id NOT IN(2))
        OR
        (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'featured' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 1)
    )
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 4
```

So we query the post, post meta and taxonomy tables and make two possible conditions:

- The category ID is not 2, **OR**
- The `featured` meta key of the post is set to `1` (change this to whatever key / value depending of how you store the "featured" information).

For that kind of specific cases, `get_posts` isn't really good to play with - querying the DB with `WPDB` will give you much more flexibility.

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    WHERE 
        $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id AND
        (
            ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id NOT IN(2))
            OR
            ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'featured' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 1)
        )
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
    LIMIT 4"
);
```

Let me know if you run into any issue as it is an untested query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly , The simplest solution, not involving complicated `SQL` would be something along the lines of :

```
     // NOT TESTED ! 
if ( count(get_the_category()) > 1 ) { // this means there are more than single category
    // show the desired posts 
    } else {
    // dont show 
    }
```

read [get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) in codex

Along the same logic lines you could also use [wp_get_post_categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories)

Comment: I don't really see how it respond to the OP needs, as he want to display the posts if it's not in a specific category **OR** if in this category **AND**  is featured.

Comment: @vard - this is an easy solution to check if a post has only one category assigned. I did not do the whole homework or write the whole code for the OP just pointed out the easy direction. Applied correctly with simple category conditionals it will work just fine. try for yourself . I have been using it on a live site for 3 years now .

Comment: You didn't understand what the OP is asking. In his case, he have posts that can be in one or more categories, those posts can be in a category that shouldn't appear on homepage **but** they should if they are **featured** (some meta probably referring this). Your answer doesn't address this situation in any way.

Comment: @vard , I might be wrong , and as much as I can admire your `SQL` skills - but I think that you did not understand my answer, or do not know how to apply it , the op asked `I want to only exclude the posts that has one category as "community-posts" if it has this category and more its shows normally..`   (see also title ).. No mentioned of `featured-post` as intended in `wordpress` context ( called `sticky` BTW ), and even if it were , a simple check of `is_sticky($post_ID);` will do.  and if it is a custom meta than a check for `get_post_meta()` will do. it is very trivial. –